# Createjs function

Tags: createjs, animate-cc

I am trying to convert an old simulation from Flash to createjs with animate cc. The only code you have is to rotate a piece but I can not get it to work. This code not work:

```
function spinit()
                {
                    var ang = myangle * Math.PI / 180;
                    this.pin1.x = disk1.x + R * Math.cos(ang);
                    this.pin1.y = disk1.y + R * Math.sin(ang);
                    this.yoke1.x = pin1.x;
                    this.disk1.rotate = myangle; 
                    this.myangle = myangle + 1;
                    if (myangle > 360)
                    {
                        myangle = 0;
                    } 
                } 
                var myangle = 0;
                var R = 90;
                setInterval(spinit, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good this is a scope issue. Your `spinit` method is being called anonymously, so it won't have access to any of your frame content referenced with `this`. You can get around this by scoping your method, and binding your setInterval call.

```
this.spinit = function() // 1. scope the function
{
   var ang = myangle * Math.PI / 180;
   this.pin1.x = disk1.x + R * Math.cos(ang);

   // etc
   setInterval(spinit.bind(this), 5); // 2. bind this so it calls in the right scope.
}
```

Make sure to call `this.spinit()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Lanny,
I see that I did not have a good syntax, but there is something that I must be doing wrong because I have not yet managed to make it work.